# Initializing multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

How to initialize a vector of vectors?

The code below crashes my application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< unsigned short > > table;
    for(unsigned short a = 0; a < 13; a++){
        for(unsigned short b = 0; b < 4; b++){
            table[a][b] = 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a size 13 vector of size 4 vectors, with each element set to 50.

```
using std::vector; // to make example shorter
vector<vector<unsigned short>> table(13, vector<unsigned short>(4, 50));
```

Comment: Thanks but you forgot a parentheses at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize it first:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short > > table;
table.resize(13);
for(unsigned short a = 0; a < 13; a++){
    table[a].resize(4);
    for(unsigned short b = 0; b < 4; b++){
        table[a][b] = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the loops at all to do this initialization.